# Visualize clustering with mulidimensional data set

Tags: clustering, data-visualization

I have done a clustering in R using the `Mclust`package with a data set with 17 attributes and 2000 observations. the `Mclust`package is using EM algorithm to do the clustering.

Is there any good way to visualize my clustering? 
My first thought is PCA.

Comment: Your first thought is not bad! Do that first and then consider more advanced techniques (eg. $t$-SNE, MDS, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

A [parallel coordinates plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates), coloring by cluster is a common way to see all the dimensions.